# Replace contents of link jquery with changing URL

Tags: jquery

I need someone to solve this issue I'm having with a link of mine.

This is my link to a blog and the URL changes, so the jquery shouldn't be hard coded. The class on this link will not change.

Example 1

```
<a class="example" href="http://www.blogname.com/blog_title_here">Hello World</a>
```

Meanwhile, I have a manually created "read more" link that is hard coded beneath the blog preview with a "different class" that will not change. I would like only the href from the dynamic link to replace the read more link.

Replace this URL...

```
<a class="differentclass" href="http://javascript:void(0);">Read More</a>
```

...with the dynamically changing URL from example 1 and this would be the end result.

```
<a class="differentclass" href="http://www.blogname.com/blog_title_here">Read More</a>
```

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two URLs?  Also, why are you replacing `javascript:void(0)` when Javascript is on?  That won't work when Javascript is off; it makes more sense to just leave the `differentclass` URL as the real URL and prevent default link behavior on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question but wouldnt a simple:

`<a class="differentclass" href="http://javascript:void(0);" id="ReadMoreLink">Read More</a`>

and the script:

```
$("#ReadMoreLink").attr("href",$(".example").attr("href"));
```

fix it?

Comment: Yes, you understood. Copy the link from top and replace it with the fake link at the bottom. I don't have an ID, just a class. This works great!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('a.differentclass').attr('href', $('a.example').attr('href') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you will need some event that triggers the change in the link.  I made a JSFIDDLE here: http://jsfiddle.net/zDLCs/1/.  When you click the button, the link changes.  The code to change the link is here:

```
$('.differentclass').attr('href',$('.example').attr('href'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDefaultUrl(); return false;" >...</a>
```

when the function looks like:

```
function openDefaultUrl() {
   window.location = $("a.example").attr("href");
}
```